# How to add restriction to a integer leaf with set of values in yang

Tags: yang

I want to set restriction to my yang leaf
I tried something like this

```
 leaf remind-me-before {
     tailf:info "Remind me before value";
         type uint16 {
              range "30, 25, 10, 5, 7";
         }    
     }
  }
```

but it throws an error saying
error: bad argument value "30, 25, 10, 5, 7", should be of type range-arg

Can someone say how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the syntax as below -

```
leaf remind-me-before {
     tailf:info "Remind me before value";
         type uint16 {
              range "30 | 25 | 10 | 5 | 7"; >>> separated by '|'
         }    
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @jeyashree it works with ascending order, otherwise, it throws ```error: the range value 75 is not larger than 90```.
But, for my knowledge, what is this representation? is it just acting as a delimiter or something else?

Comment: Or is it a general way of representing range not just in yang?
Where can I refer to this syntax?

Comment: @Lohit - General syntax of range-arg  = range-part *(optsep "|" optsep range-part) . You can read more about it from RFC - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6020#section-12